# How should I create a background thread?

Tags: c#, .net

The thread created by the  following is the foreground thread

```
  Thread workingThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoJob));
```

Can I make the thread created background?

Comment: You should give proper title to your question like "How should I create a background thread ?", because it  confuses other programmers with your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161133/background-or-foreground-thread

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can; `System.Threading.Thread` has an [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether or not a thread is a background thread.

```
Thread workingThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoJob))
                                 { IsBackground = true };
```

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an older thread, but the most practical solution how create new Thread is this:

```
 new Thread(() => NameOfYourMethod()) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

If you need to create paramerized Thread, just do simple modification:

```
 new Thread(() => NameOfYourMethod(param1, param2...)) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

And that's all, I hope it helps someone :)

*<sub>*Use this only if you don't need to store Treads for some reason.*</sub>

Comment: There's no reason to duplicate an answer that's already been posted *four times* already, seven years ago.

Comment: lol, my answer is not duplicate, I don't see same answer nowhere above. I know all says "IsBackground" but everytime must create new Thread with name or used old method, in my solution I'm using newest method and without any name declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
workingThread.IsBackGround = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:-

```
    Thread.IsBackground = true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoJob)) { IsBackground = true };
```

Should be IsBackground, not IsBackGround