# Background or Foreground thread?

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone summerize the thread created/used by .net foreground or background?

Some cases are:

- Direct creation by using new thread
- Use threadpool thread
- use Async programming model like delegate.beginInvoke etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [background or foreground thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161120/background-or-foreground-thread)

Comment: It is the different question.

Comment: Why is it a different question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Threading in C#...](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)await some of the experts responses here as well.